# Determinant of $I-aa^T+bb^T$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

Are there any nice formulas for exactly computing the determinant of identity - rank 2 matrix, e.g.

$$\det(M) = \det(I-aa^T+bb^T)?$$

Here we cannot assume that $a$ and $b$ are orthogonal. ($a^Tb > 0$.)

I think it is ok to use projections on range spaces, e.g.

$$
proj_{range(a)} = \frac{1}{a^Ta} aa^T, \quad proj_{range(a)^\perp} = I - \frac{1}{a^Ta} aa^T.
$$

But the answer is still not clear to me.

Thanks!

Comment: [Sylvester's determinant identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_determinant_identity): $\det(I+AB) = \det(I+BA)$ where $A = \pmatrix{a & b}$, $B = \pmatrix{-a^T\cr b^T}$.

Comment: I was suprised when I found out that $\det(I - ab^T) = \det(I - a^Tb)$. (Note that the matrix on the left is not the same size as the one on the right.). I wonder if this can be generalized to your problem?

Comment: Thanks to both of you! This identity is very slick!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get there by just going through the rank-1-update formulas for determinants and inverses: the [matrix determinant lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma) and the [Woodbury matrix identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity).

In particular, we first need to find $(\mathbf I - \mathbf a \mathbf a^{\mathsf T})^{-1}$, which by the Woodbury identity (or by [some of its special cases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula)) is $\mathbf I + \frac{\mathbf a \mathbf a^{\mathsf T}}{1 - \mathbf a \boldsymbol{\cdot} \mathbf a}$. Next, plug this into
$$
   \det(\mathbf I - \mathbf a \mathbf a^{\mathsf T} + \mathbf b \mathbf b^{\mathsf T}) = (1 + \mathbf b^{\mathsf T}(\mathbf I - \mathbf a \mathbf a^{\mathsf T})^{-1} \mathbf b) \det(\mathbf I - \mathbf a \mathbf a^{\mathsf T})
$$
and apply the matrix determinant lemma to $\det(\mathbf I - \mathbf a \mathbf a^{\mathsf T})$. The final answer should be
$$
  \det(\mathbf I - \mathbf a \mathbf a^{\mathsf T} + \mathbf b \mathbf b^{\mathsf T}) = (1 + \mathbf b \boldsymbol\cdot \mathbf b)(1-\mathbf a\boldsymbol\cdot \mathbf a) + (\mathbf a \boldsymbol\cdot \mathbf b)^2.
$$

Comment: Thanks! I didn't think to use the Woodbury inversion lemma. Very clean proof!